# How do I test fulltext fields using sunspot_matchers in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sunspot

My search controller does this:

```
search = Sunspot.search(Item) do
  fulltext params[:q] do
    fields(:foo, :bar, :bletch)
  end
end
```

And in my rspec controller test I have the following:

```
get :show, :q => q

expect(Sunspot.session).to have_search_params(:fulltext, q, proc do
  fields(:foo, :bar, :bletch)
end)
```

Side note: when I tried using a block instead of a proc, the block was never executed:

```
have_search_params(:fulltext, q) do
  # This block was never executed
end
```

My support/sunspot.rb contains only the following:

```
Sunspot.session = SunspotMatchers::SunspotSessionSpy.new(Sunspot.session)
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
  1) SearchController GET search when a user runs a search performs a fulltext search on the right fields
     Failure/Error: fields(:foo, :bar, :bletch)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `fields' for #<Sunspot::DSL::Search:0x007fa0f0da0168>
     # ./spec/controllers/search_controller_spec.rb:28:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/search_controller_spec.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What's the right way to test that my controller is supplying the correct params when doing a fulltext search? Google yields no relevant results when querying this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer from Joseph Palermo at https://github.com/pivotal/sunspot_matchers/issues/23. He doesn't have an SO account, so he gave me permission to reproduce his answer here:

> With regards to the first question. The reason the do/end block
>   doesn't get executed when you use that syntax has to do with operator
>   precedence in Ruby. In that case, the block is actually being passed
>   to the expect method I believe, and not the have_search_params method.
>   Blocks defined using curly braces have a higher operator precedence
>   and thus bind to have_search_params where you want them.
>
> Now for the actual error that you are getting. When you pass a block
>   or proc to the have_search_params matcher, it only takes one other
>   argument, the type of match to look for. All the actual query data
>   should be specified in the block/proc itself.
>
> ```
> get :show, :q => q
>
> expect(Sunspot.session).to have_search_params(:fulltext) {
>   fulltext q do
>     fields(:foo, :bar, :bletch)
>   end
> }
> ```